# Windows 10 x64 very poor performance and heavy IO usage

Tags: windows-10, performance

After a clean install of windows 10 it was very unstable and poor performance, to open Explorer for example took ~10 secs and it freeze/unfreezing constantly.

And I've observed a heavy disk IO.

What's the probable problem and solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching and tries I've found the problem.

The problem in that case was the `Sata Mode` that was set to `IDE`, after setting it to `AHCI` and booted in safe mode (to install de `AHCI` drivers) the windows is now smoothly.